# POST Retrofit 2x raw JSONArray String in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

How to post raw jsonArray string in kotlin using retrofit

im having **timeout** response on **onFailure** method

here is sample of string  array i want to post

> [{"username":"username4"},{"username":"username2"}]

here is my endpoint definition

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @POST("insert/createuser")
    fun postuser(@Body logs:String ):Call<ArrRes>
```

here are my classes

```
class ArrRes{

    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    var username: String = ""

    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    var message: String = ""

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    var status: String = ""
}
```

here is my posting method

var obj = JSONObject();
        var arr = JSONArray();

```
    for (i in 0  until 5){
        obj.put("username","username${i}");
        arr.put(obj);
    }

    Log.i("app:sync","${arr.toString()}")

    mService!!.postuser(arr.toString()).enqueue(
           object : Callback<LogResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<LogResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.i("app:retro:service", "onFailure ${t.message}")
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<LogResponse>, response: Response<LogResponse>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.i("app:retro:service", "onResponse true ${response.body()!!.toString()}")
                    } else {
                        Log.i("app:retro:service", "onResponse false ${response.raw().toString()}")
                    }
                }
           }
    )
```

here is sample success post using postman

[image]

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: That depends on what your web service will be expecting to have posted. Can you add some info about that and also your retrofit endpoint definition.

Comment: Thanks for replying . my web service is python. that will received sa text/json and have a response . I updated my question with sample success post using postman

Comment: How about your Retrofit endpoint definition?

Comment: ohh sorry i forgot will update again.

Comment: now updated thanks for helping bro Ivan  :) i hope you can help me solve this

Comment: If your error is a timeout from the server, your issue has nothing to do with your code. This seems server-side..

Comment: Thank you for your help guys I have solve it by adding converter-scalars dependencies need by retrofit. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by adding this dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$version'
```

*There are multiple existing Retrofit converters for various data formats. You can serialize and deserialize Java objects to JSON or XML or any other data format and vice versa. Within the available converters, you’ll also find a Retrofit Scalars Converter that does the job of parsing any Java primitive to be put within the request body. Conversion applies to both directions: requests and responses.*
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-send-plain-text-request-body